# Using a class that inherits a template class as a constructor parameter in the template class?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have the following:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {};
```

and a descendant class,

```
class Bar : public Foo<some_typename>{};
```

How would I go about passing Bar to Foo's constructor without Foo.h including Bar.h, if that is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

it's unusual, but there often ways around it, depending on your needs (elaborate, perhaps?).

understand that it only makes sense to pass another Bar to a Foo.

in this case, you could:

1) create a second template parameter in Foo and lay out the interface required at construction:

```
template < typename T, typename Bar_ >
class Foo {
   /* ... */
   Foo(Bar_& bar) : weight_(bar.getWeight()) {
   }
   /* ... */
```

2) or just use a template ctor:

```
template < typename Bar_ >
Foo(Bar_& bar) : weight_(bar.getWeight()) {
}
```

3) if Foo+Bar is lightweight, you could just create an extended initialization list, used by the Bar at init.

4) since it is a template (and the implementation must be visible to its subclass and has special linkage), you could also declare a Foo ctor which takes a Bar by pointer, then just define the Foo constructor in Bar.hpp

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the ["Curiously recurring template pattern" (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).